# Error in proving inequality $1 - x \leq e^{-x}$

Tags: inequality

Fact states as following,

$$1 - x \leq e^{-x}$$

This is how I try to prove it:

\begin{align*}
 \ln (1 - x) &\leq \ln (e^{-x})\\
 \ln 1/ \ln x &\leq  -x\\
 \ln 1 &\leq -x \times \ln x \qquad\\
 0 &\leq -x \times \ln x \qquad \text{since }\ln 1 = 0\\
\end{align*}
so LHS of the inequality must be non-negative number. if you try with x = 9, then $-9 \times ln 9 = -19$ and if you try to put x = -9, then you are not able to work out the natural logarithm because the minus. So, my prove is wrong 100% but I don't know where, another thing in the book that I found this fact, the author just states that it is fact, so I wonder if this fact has a name.

Thank you,

Comment: You cannot take the logarithm of a (maybe) negative quantity, but for sure $\log(1-x)$ is not $\frac{\log 1}{\log x}$, also because $\log(1)=0$.

Comment: A one-line proof is given by considering that $e^{-x}$ is a convex function and $1-x$ is the equation of the tangent in the origin.

Comment: You have the log property backwards. It's not that $\ln(a-b)=\ln a/\ln b$, it's that $\log(a/b)=\ln a-\ln b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Another proof:** For $0<x<1$, we have $x^m-\frac{x^{m+1}}{m} = x^m(1-\frac{x}{m}) >0$, thus  $$e^{-x} = 1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots > 1 - x$$

by Taylor series.

For $x\geq1$, we have positive $\geq$ non-positive.

For $x<0$, take $t=-x$ and apply the usual $e^t\geq1+t$, easliy provable by Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

Just observe that for $0< x< 1$
$$\ln (1-x)\neq 0 = \ln 1/\ln x$$