# Exponential Function - inequality 3

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I need to show that
$$
1-x\leq e^{-x} (*)
$$
Now we know that $e^x:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$, which means
$$
e^{-x}:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}=1-x+\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}...
$$
So after we subtract $1-x$ from both sides of the inequation (*) we have to show:
$$
0\leq \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}=\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}...
$$

1.) $x=0$ : $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!} = 0$

2.)$x=1$: $\frac{1}{2n+1}\leq \frac{1}{2n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

3.) $x<0$: This is obvious since ever summand is positive.

4.) $0<x<1$: This is also obvious (?) because for such $x$ it holds that $x^{2n}>x^{2n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and also $\frac{1}{(2n)!}>\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}$. So $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!} - \frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}>0
$ since all summands are positive.

5.) $x>1$: Here is where I struggle and need help please. This is the a bit of the opposite of 4 maybe.

Comment: one approach is to show equality holds when $x=0$ and look at the derivative of both sides

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1417356/42969.

Comment: You may just use the fact that $e^{-x}$ is a convex function, hence its graph lies above the graph of the tangent line at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $e^{-x}+x-1$ is $-e^{-x}+1 \geq 0$ because $e^{-x} \leq 1$. This function vanishes when $x=0$ and hence it is non-negative for $x \geq 0$. This gives $e^{-x} \geq 1-x$ for $x \geq 0$. For $x<0$ the inequality follows immediately from the series expansion (since all the terms are positive).

Comment: $e^{-x} \geq 1-x$ holds for all real numbers. The question is a duplicate, though.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the comment.